# When I click Register button it appear to crash my apps after I filled the information details

Tags: android, json

This is my Register.java

```
public class Register extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener{
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.pmss.MESSAGE";

Button registernow;
EditText nametext,useridtext,passwordtext,confirmpasswordtext,mobilenumbertext,addresstext,citytext,postcodetext,statetext;
// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

private static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://192.168.1.14/PMSS/register.php";
//ids
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    registernow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registernow);
    nametext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nametext);
    useridtext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.useridtext);
    passwordtext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordtext);
    confirmpasswordtext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.confirmpasswordtext);
    mobilenumbertext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobilenumbertext);
    addresstext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addresstext);
    postcodetext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.postcodetext);
    citytext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.citytext);
    statetext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.statetext);


    registernow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String Name = nametext.getText().toString();
            String Email = useridtext.getText().toString();
            String Password = passwordtext.getText().toString();    
            String ConfirmPassword = confirmpasswordtext.getText().toString();
            String MobileNumber = mobilenumbertext.getText().toString();
            String Address = addresstext.getText().toString();
            String PostCode = postcodetext.getText().toString();
            String City = citytext.getText().toString();
            String State = statetext.getText().toString();
            new CreateUser(Name,Email,Password,ConfirmPassword,MobileNumber,Address,PostCode,City,State).execute();

        }
    });
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        /*case R.id.action_search:
            return true;

        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;*/

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

class CreateUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, Integer> {

     /**
    * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
    * */
    boolean failure = false;
    String res;
    int success;
    String Name,Email,Password,ConfirmPassword,MobileNumber,Address,PostCode,City,State;
    public CreateUser(String Name,String Email,String Password,String ConfirmPassword,String MobileNumber,String Address,String PostCode,String City,String State) {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Email = Email;
        this.Password = Password;
        this.ConfirmPassword = ConfirmPassword;
        this.MobileNumber = MobileNumber;
        this.Address = Address;
        this.PostCode = PostCode;
        this.City = City;
        this.State = State;        
    }

   protected void onPreExecute() {
       super.onPreExecute();
       pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
       pDialog.setMessage("Creating New User...");
       pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
       pDialog.setCancelable(true);
       pDialog.show();
   }

    protected Integer doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         // Check for success tag

       try {
           // Building Parameters
           List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
           params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", Name));
           params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", Email));
           params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", Password));
           params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("confirmpassword", ConfirmPassword));
           params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobilenumber", MobileNumber));
           params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("address", Address));
           params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("city", City));
           params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("postcode", PostCode));
           params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("state", State));


           Log.d("request!", "starting");

           //Posting user data to script
           JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                  REGISTER_URL, "POST", params);

           // full json response
           Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

        // json success element
           success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
           res = json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

           return success;
       } catch (JSONException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

       return null;

    }
    /**
    * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
    * **/
   protected void onPostExecute(Integer success) {
       // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
       pDialog.dismiss();

       if (success != null && success == 1) {
        Log.d("User Created!", res);
        Intent r = new Intent(Register.this, Login.class);
        startActivity(r);
        finish();
        Toast.makeText(Register.this, res == null? "Please enter the require field that marked with **" : res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        nametext.setText(null);
        useridtext.setText(null);
        passwordtext.setText(null);
        confirmpasswordtext.setText(null);
        mobilenumbertext.setText(null);
        addresstext.setText(null);
        citytext.setText(null);
        postcodetext.setText(null);
        statetext.setText(null);

       }else{
        Log.d("Login Failure!", "res: " + res);
            Toast.makeText(Register.this, res == null? "Please enter the require field that marked with **" : res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       }

   }

}

}
```

This is my logcat (after I click register button)

```
12-08 21:16:26.409: W/System.err(11483): org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to /192.168.1.14:80 timed out
12-08 21:16:26.409: W/System.err(11483):    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121)
12-08 21:16:26.409: W/System.err(11483):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:143)
12-08 21:16:26.409: W/System.err(11483):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
12-08 21:16:26.409: W/System.err(11483):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
12-08 21:16:26.409: W/System.err(11483):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:359)
12-08 21:16:26.419: W/System.err(11483):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
12-08 21:16:26.419: W/System.err(11483):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
12-08 21:16:26.419: W/System.err(11483):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
12-08 21:16:26.419: W/System.err(11483):    at com.pmss.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:97)
12-08 21:16:26.419: W/System.err(11483):    at com.pmss.Register$CreateUser.doInBackground(Register.java:164)
12-08 21:16:26.419: W/System.err(11483):    at com.pmss.Register$CreateUser.doInBackground(Register.java:1)
12-08 21:16:26.419: W/System.err(11483):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
12-08 21:16:26.419: W/System.err(11483):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
12-08 21:16:26.419: W/System.err(11483):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
12-08 21:16:26.419: W/System.err(11483):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
12-08 21:16:26.429: W/System.err(11483):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
12-08 21:16:26.429: W/System.err(11483):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
12-08 21:16:26.429: E/Buffer Error(11483): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
12-08 21:16:26.429: E/JSON Parser(11483): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
12-08 21:16:26.439: W/dalvikvm(11483): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
12-08 21:16:26.459: E/AndroidRuntime(11483): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-08 21:16:26.459: E/AndroidRuntime(11483): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-08 21:16:26.459: E/AndroidRuntime(11483):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
12-08 21:16:26.459: E/AndroidRuntime(11483):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
12-08 21:16:26.459: E/AndroidRuntime(11483):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
12-08 21:16:26.459: E/AndroidRuntime(11483):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
12-08 21:16:26.459: E/AndroidRuntime(11483):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
12-08 21:16:26.459: E/AndroidRuntime(11483):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
12-08 21:16:26.459: E/AndroidRuntime(11483):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
12-08 21:16:26.459: E/AndroidRuntime(11483):    at     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
12-08 21:16:26.459: E/AndroidRuntime(11483): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-08 21:16:26.459: E/AndroidRuntime(11483):    at com.pmss.Register$CreateUser.doInBackground(Register.java:168)
12-08 21:16:26.459: E/AndroidRuntime(11483):    at com.pmss.Register$CreateUser.doInBackground(Register.java:1)
12-08 21:16:26.459: E/AndroidRuntime(11483):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
12-08 21:16:26.459: E/AndroidRuntime(11483):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
12-08 21:16:26.459: E/AndroidRuntime(11483):    ... 4 more
12-08 21:16:32.109: E/WindowManager(11483): Activity com.pmss.Register has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@405b7ae0 that was originally added here
12-08 21:16:32.109: E/WindowManager(11483): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.pmss.Register has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@405b7ae0 that was originally added here
12-08 21:16:32.109: E/WindowManager(11483):     at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:263)
12-08 21:16:32.109: E/WindowManager(11483):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
12-08 21:16:32.109: E/WindowManager(11483):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
12-08 21:16:32.109: E/WindowManager(11483):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
12-08 21:16:32.109: E/WindowManager(11483):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
12-08 21:16:32.109: E/WindowManager(11483):     at com.pmss.Register$CreateUser.onPreExecute(Register.java:140)
12-08 21:16:32.109: E/WindowManager(11483):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
12-08 21:16:32.109: E/WindowManager(11483):     at com.pmss.Register$1.onClick(Register.java:74)
12-08 21:16:32.109: E/WindowManager(11483):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
12-08 21:16:32.109: E/WindowManager(11483):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
12-08 21:16:32.109: E/WindowManager(11483):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-08 21:16:32.109: E/WindowManager(11483):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-08 21:16:32.109: E/WindowManager(11483):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-08 21:16:32.109: E/WindowManager(11483):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
12-08 21:16:32.109: E/WindowManager(11483):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-08 21:16:32.109: E/WindowManager(11483):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-08 21:16:32.109: E/WindowManager(11483):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
12-08 21:16:32.109: E/WindowManager(11483):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
12-08 21:16:32.109: E/WindowManager(11483):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

line 97: `HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);`

line 164: `JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(`

line 168: `Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());`

line 140: `pDialog.show();`

line 74: `new CreateUser(Name,Email,Password,ConfirmPassword,MobileNumber,Address,PostCode,City,State).execute();`

Can anyone guide me what should I do to overcome this problem? If needed me to post more of my coding just tell me.
Although I have saw the JSON Parser tag in my logcat, it should be related to JSON problem I think?

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because your json is null (error on line 168 when you try to call `json.toString()` )

It may be because your json is not well parsed (error in json format) or because the application failed in accessing the remote file.

After your `jsonParser.makeHttpRequest()`, check if your json object is not null, and continue operations if it's not null.

If it is null, debug your error.

Comment: My json is null and What should I do so that json is not null?

Comment: You should to handle this error in your code. Your json null means json is not well formated or remote file can not be accessed. You should to handle this case in your code.

Comment: found it in my register.php script where email `textfield` I put input type="text" which my `EditText` `android:inputType="textEmailAddress"` how can the email input type to be post on text input type.. silly mistake